# Facebook C# SDK Authorization Flow Example

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am looking for a good example for the Facebook C# SDK authorization flow. I am upgrading to version 6 of the SDK and I am having trouble understanding the new flow.  I am using the following components:

Asp.net MVC3 Web application
Facebook C# SDK v6
FB Javascript SDK

I am trying to pass the access_token from the FB Javascript SDK to the server for further use.

This flow is outlined in the new documentation at:

http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started

I have a the following questions:

1. Why are they passing the access token in a post vs parsing it out of the cookie.
2. Don't we need to verify the signed request at the server side before trusting the access token?

Answer (score 0):

First you to have to Follow the conventions that Facebook Javascript SDK is giving to work it with C# SDK.

Answers.
1. Javascript SDK need post back of the page after login in to Facebook. You thoughts are right about getting token from cookie but think what **if cookie is disable on browser?** Posting access token is the best choice in both cases.

2.Access token already encrypted by Facebook so you dont need to worry about them. If you want more security then you **enable encrypted access token** in you app settings.

See http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/572/.

Another thing is that if somehow somebody pass the invalid access token(XSS attack) in post back then also you don't need to worry because access token is validated on Graph API servers, so there less possibilities to effect your Facebook account. You can also enable HTTPS of site to make it more secure.

That's all what I have.

Thanks
Happy Socializing.. ;)

Dharmendra.

Comment: How would making his website a https website make it more secure if the OAuth authentication is already encrypted over a https connection?

Comment: If the access token is not validated against the signed request, wouldn't this be vulnerable to token hijacking?  I noticed the standard FB PHP examples validate against the signed request.